# Output create SQL with Entity Framework 4.1 Code-First

Tags: .net, ef-code-first, entity-framework-4.1

`Database.SetInitializer()` works great for testing, but I need the SQL output in a file for working in a production environment (DBAs aren't going to run a program to create the DB).  Castle ActiveRecord make output to a file easy with `ActiveRecordStarter.GenerateCreationScripts()`.  If there's a similar method in EF, I'm unable to find any mention of it.  Is this doable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well you could run the Database.SetInitializer() method to create the initial database for you and then once you are satisfied with the database schema then you could possibly use something like SQL Server Management Studio to generate the script from the database

Comment: +1 I think it is the only option in the current version of the API.

Comment: SQL Server Management Studio did what I needed.  Thanks much.

Answer (score 9):

You can also use the DbContext to get the Sql DDL.

```
string sqlscript = (context as IObjectContextAdapter).ObjectContext.CreateDatabaseScript();
```

Comment: sweet! didnt know about this, the string can be saved into a file;

Comment: I think I liked this answer best :-)

Comment: Yes, definitely the best answer.

Comment: Just tested this and it generates the schema properly, but does not include nonclustered indexes, like the ones included when you have code-first recreate the db from within your app. Otherwise the schemas are the same.

Answer (score 0):

i think the [Entity Designer Database Generation Power Pack](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2010/02/08/entity-designer-database-generation-power-pack.aspx) is probably what you're looking for.

Comment: It doesn't work with the code first. It works only with the model first using EDMX file.